# NDI Polaris for orientation measurement

Tags: ros, stacks, tracking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All!
I would like to use the a ndi tracking system with ros and found the link: http://www.ros.org/news/2010/09/ndi-polaris-driver-in-kul-ros-pkg.html

Does anyone have used that before and can tell me in detail what do i need to install and how can i use the package/stack for measuring? I do face some problems while applying a rosmake.

So please let me know how I can save orientation data measured by the ndi hardware.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32286/ndi-polaris-for-orientation-measurement/) by [rascal](https://answers.ros.org/users/2220/rascal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the polaris driver was written to work with Orocos RTT 1.0 and no longer builds against the toolchain-2.5 branch or the fuerte rtt_ros_integration.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0